# .NET Cognito Authentication JWTBearer

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito, awscognitotoken

**SCENARIO**

I am trying to provide authentication for my web application APIs with AWS-Cognito and JWTBearer.

**PROBLEM**

Currently, my client performs a GET call and is met with a 401 (Unauthorized) message. This prompts the client to redirect to Cognito UI for log-in and the token. Once performed, we're turned back to the web application.

When the token has been provided, I attach it to a header and perform the request again. This doesn't get validated by the server, and we end up in a loop.

It feels as though JWTBearer is not doing anything.

**SERVER** .NET 5.0

***Startup.cs***

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

...

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    
                    options.Authority = "https://{domain}.{location}.amazoncognito.com/{PoolId}";
                    options.Audience = "http://localhost:5000";
                });
...
}
```

```
public void Configure(iApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

...

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

...

}
```

***Controller***

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetItems(ICollection<Data> collection){...}
```

**CLIENT** React

```
//Token = "Bearer AccessToken"

fetch(config.getResourceUrl, {headers: {Authentication: Token}})
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status > 400) {
            window.location.replace("{Cognito UI}");
        } else {
            return res.json();

        })
```

Comment: Can you share working sample in GitHub?

Comment: Hi Natheeshkumar, sorry I can't but is there anything, in particular, you'd like help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem:

```
fetch(config.getResourceUrl, {headers: {Authentication: Token}})
```

The header should have read **Authorization** instead.

```
fetch(config.getResourceUrl, {headers: {Authorization: Token}})
```